# Uploading a csv file at AWS

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I am new to Amazon web services and couldn't figure out uploading a csv file to AWS EC2 instance where a web server is running.

I am using File upload widget (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) to select and upload file to a existing directory under /var/www. The site works on a local webserver but I am getting the following response from webserve at AWS.

```
delete_type:"DELETE"
delete_url:"/gook/upload.php?file=Example.csv"
error:"abort"
name:"Example.csv"
size:false
type:"text/csv"
```

Locally, the response contain a valid size and there is no abort error. Any hint/reference to make changes are really appreciated.